# How do I properly pass System.Net.NetworkCredential to WCF Client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I currently have client device that prompts the user for user/pass and creates a `System.Net.NetworkCredential` that is passed to a *WCF* Service.  This *WCF* Service then uses the credential to use on another external service.

The problem is that whenever I pass through the `System.Net.NetworkCredential` to the service it seems to lose the password field and so I never get it to authenticate with the external service. I've tested just passing in plain text/strings as user/pass and it works but feel like this is not great for security (although I do have HTTPS enabled for all traffic between the two services).

Is there a way to pass these credentials to the service correctly?

Here is some test code on the *WCF* service:

```
public string TestCred(System.Net.NetworkCredential c, string username, string pass)
{

    cred = c;
    userName = username;
    passWord = pass;
    string s = cred.UserName + cred.Password + "end";
    return s;

}
```

I have it return that string to test what is actually received at the Service side and the password is completely blank (the username makes it there ok).

Here is the code I use on the *WCF* service to contact the external service:

```
externalService.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(cred.UserName, cred.Password, "domain");
```

This doesn't work since the cred.Password field is blank, also I've tried:

```
externalService.Credentials = cred;
```

Which also fails.

When I use the plain strings though it works great:

```
externalService.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord, "domain");
```

Any suggestions?  Since the connection between the client device-WCF and Service-External Service are all *HTTPS-SSL* required, it is slightly secure but I didn't feel great passing user/pass with strings.

Comment: This class(System.Net.NetworkCredential) does not support public key-based authentication methods such as Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client authentication

Comment: Just pass the same credential object. Why are you try to create a new one? The Password field isn't accessible for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @VinayKumar.o NetworkCredentials has absolutely nothing to do with transport encryption like SSL. It's the class that stores credentials that will be used by libraries for whatever reason. WCF does support SSL

Comment: @user3393394 what are you trying to do? Why does your *client* pass credentials to the service? This is a *very* strange scenario. Are you trying to *impersonate* the client? There are standard-based ways to do this that don't involve breaking security by moving passwords around.

Comment: Check [Delegation and Impersonation with WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088(v=vs.110).aspx) and [How To: Impersonate a client on a service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the TokenImpersonationLevel?
[MSDN: TokenImpersonationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.tokenimpersonationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
                var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            reportChannel.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
            reportChannel.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(credentials);
```

Comment: Impersonation is the answer yet this code doesn't explain how to do this. This is configured on the *service* with the `OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Required)` attribute. The line that sets the `AllowedImpersonationLevel` only allows a credential to be used for impersonation on a service that *does* allow it in the first place